# Android wake up and notification when SMS received

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sleep

I'm trying to create an app to receive incoming SMS with specific content and show a notification(with sound) even if the phone is in sleep mode. The app working fine if the phone is not in sleep mode. But as soon as the phone is in sleep, I'll get the notification after I manually wake up the phone. I have the necessary permissions in the manifest file, and I also implemented the full_wake_lock function.

This is my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".BroadcastNewSms"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
    public class BroadcastNewSms extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("LOG'", " - broadcast created");
        setContentView(R.layout.androidexample_broadcast_newsms);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    }
}
```

Broadcastreceiver:

```
    public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("LOG'"," - onreceive called");
        WakeLocker.acquire(context);

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    if (message.equals("test")) {

                        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                        int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Sender: "+ senderNum + ", Message: " + message, duration);
                        toast.show();

                        final int NOTIF_ID = 1234;
                        NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "New sms", System.currentTimeMillis());
                        PendingIntent intent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, IncomingSms.class), 0);
                        note.setLatestEventInfo(context, "New sms", "You have one unread message.", intent2);
                        notifManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, note);
                        Log.i("LOG'"," - notified");
                        // notifManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
                        WakeLocker.release();
                        //abortBroadcast();
                    }
                }
              }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceive", "Exception" +e);

        }

    }

}
```

WakeLocker:

```
    public abstract class WakeLocker {
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public static void acquire(Context ctx) {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "mysms1");
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public static void release() {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

I don't really know what can be the problem, but I spent 3 days to find it...
I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the emulator itself. Even the rtc_wakeup function was not working. I tried my app on a real device and working fine...